# Kotlin (if else)

Tags: kotlin

I'm new to kotlin. I need to make a calculator using enam. At the end of the code, there is a function that reads the action and returns the enam. The function works but, "if else" doesn't. Need console calculator, not in android studio.Please help!
All code from file
import java.lang.Exception

```
fun main() {

    print("first number: ")
    val first : Int = readNumber()

    print("second number: ")
    val second : Int = readNumber()

    println("Enter action: +, -, *, /")
    val sum : Int = first + second

   println("Answer: $sum ")
}

fun readNumber() :Int{
    return try {
        readLine()!!.toInt()
    }
    catch (e:Exception){
        0
    }
}


enum class Action(val symbol : String){
    PLUS("+"),
    MINUS("-"),
    MULTIPLY("*"),
    DIVIDE("/");
}

fun defineAct(){
    val pls = Action.PLUS
    val mns = Action.MINUS
    val mlt = Action.MULTIPLY
    val dvd = Action.DIVIDE

    if (val = pls){
    sum = pls + mns
        println("Ответ: ${sum}")
    else if (val - mns){
        sum = pls - mns
    }
}
```

Comment: The code you have posted isn't even valid kotlin... You have mis-matched `{}` (among other things...)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

Your are using `val` keyword inside if-else. You could change it accordingly your requirements. Hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you. And can you tell me what to change the val?

Comment: It would be helpful for you, if you check out https://www.w3schools.com/kotlin/kotlin_conditions.php and some R&D on Kotlin.

Comment: Shamim Reza, Thank You very much!